# With a Pivot Chart, how can I avoid plotting missing data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Please see my problem illustrated here:

[image]

I have received forecasting information from a customer, telling us roughly what they intend to order from us in a given month. The column months are the "source" data, i.e. reading down the second column (May): in May, they told us that they would spend £10,465 in May and also predicted that they would be spending £8,500 in June.

Each month, they provide a forecast for the upcoming months, so in June, there will be no data included for May. This is shown in the table as a zero, when in reality, it doesn't actually exist in the data and should be blank or N/A.
As the pivot table automatically sums the sales for each month, I cannot adjust the formula to show errors instead of zeros to avoid it being plotted.

As you can see in the graph, these zeros are plotted before/after each month and making it incredibly messy.

I have the data in a Pivot Chart because, with slicers, I will analyse the data from multiple months pertaining to many months in the future. I would not be able to keep up if I replicated the data in some way to create a regular excel chart. Is there any way to stop this missing data from being plotted?

Comment: Does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855689/do-not-chart-empty-cells-as-0

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately not. I can't hide any rows or columns, nor can I incorporate NA() as the data doesn't exist in the first place. I need data that is missing to be blank and not just zero.

Comment: If you right-click on the chart and choose "Pivot Table Options", Check "For Empty Cells show" and leave the text box next to it empty. I *think* it will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

*Do the followings:*

1. Click anywhere on the chart, & find the **C**hart Tools group on the ribbon.
2. From Design Tab, Select **D**ata.
3. From the Select Data Source, hit the **H**idden and Empty Cells.
4. You find **G**aps is selected by default,,  select either **Z**ero or **C**onnect Data points with Line.